# When a specific word is found, delete that row AND the 2 rows under. Is this possible with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

As the photo shows, all my data is on ONE column. The "trigger word" is "Past Car" and want that entire row PLUS the two rows under it deleted.

So according to the photo below rows 5,6,7 and 18,19,20 and 26,27,28 would be deleted.

Is this possible with VBA? I've tried using search functions and some VBA techniques but got overwhelmed.

Screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must loop through the cells in column A in `reverse order` and check if the cell content is `Past Car` and if so, delete the rows accordingly.

You may try something like this...

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1) = "Past Car" Then
        Range("A" & i).Resize(3).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do it like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelIt()
Const PAST_CAR = "Past Car"
Const OFF_SET = 3
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim deleteRange As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = PAST_CAR Then
                If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set deleteRange = .Rows(i).Resize(OFF_SET)
                Else
                    Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, .Rows(i).Resize(OFF_SET))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not (deleteRange Is Nothing) Then
        deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

In this way you do not need to loop backwards or turn of ScreenUpdatings as you only have one "write" access to the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.